# migrating from MPRA to arXiv?

Tags: arxiv, repository

I have two questions about arXiv and MPRA.

1. MPRA is a repository for papers in economics; arXiv now accepts papers in theoretical economics. What is the effective difference between the two?
2. My coauthors and I have a working paper that was deposited at MPRA slightly before arXiv started accepting work in theoretical economics. Without knowing clearly the answer to the first question, it seems that arXiv is the more natural venue for our work (in this paper and others). We have now significantly revised this paper, and would like to put it on arXiv. So

a. Is it acceptable to somehow switch from MPRA to arXiv?

b. If so, would it be acceptable to deposit the revised manuscript at both venues, so that MPRA does not display only a significantly out of date version?

This isn't an attempt to game the system to get more views or citations or whatever. It's an attempt to get as close as possible to the best possible world in which we were able to deposit on arXiv the first time around.